# Servlet spring is currently unavailable

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am using intellij, spring mvc and tiles. At least I am trying :)
I get this error when executing on tomcat:

```
HTTP Status 503 - Servlet spring is currently unavailable
The requested service (Servlet spring is currently unavailable) is not currently available.
```

I really don't know what is wrong.
Here is the tomcat output:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin\catalina.bat" run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Documents and Settings\�€…˜\.IntelliJIdea10\system\tomcat\Unnamed_project"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin\bootstrap.jar"
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.22.
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [false], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:17 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:17 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2135 ms
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/WorkingDirectory/Projects/GreenWheels/green-wheels-project/web-app-module/target/web-app-module/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/WorkingDirectory/Projects/GreenWheels/green-wheels-project/web-app-module/target/web-app-module/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-nop-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:19 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:19 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
ינו 21, 2012 2:51:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1967 ms
Connected to server
```

My web.xml is:

```
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My spring-servlet.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="Success.GreenWheels.Controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am using maven in order to load dependencies. Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>success.green-wheels</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain-library-module</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.tiles}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I am using `org.springframework.version = 3.1.0.RELEASE` and `org.apache.tiles = 2.2.2`

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can be wrong?

My guess is that Spring initialization failed.

However, there is no evidence for this in the `catalina.out` file you provided.  OTOH, there is *nothing whatsoever* from Spring in the logfile.  So I'm betting that your webapp's logging configuration have been set up to ignore all of Springs log events ... or to log them somewhere else.

Anyway, you need that evidence to find out what the real problem is.  So my advice is to change the logging configs so that the effective logging level for Spring classes is `DEBUG`, and see what the logs say.  Note, there *will* be a lot of `DEBUG` log messages: if you don't see any then you've *still* got the logging configs wrong.

---

Actually, there's a couple of other fishy things:

- The `catalina.out` file doesn't say *anything* about deploying or starting your webapp.
- The `catalina.out` file seems to be saying that there's a problem with the logging:

  ```
  SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/WorkingDirectory/Projects/GreenWheels/green-wheels-project/web-app-module/target/web-app-module/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/WorkingDirectory/Projects/GreenWheels/green-wheels-project/web-app-module/target/web-app-module/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-nop-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
  ```

  It looks like your WAR file contains two SLF4J binding JARs, and that one of them is for the "nop" binding.  I imagine that the effect of the "nop" binding is to disable all logging via the the SFL4J facade ... and that's how Spring does its logging IIRC.